# What are roots of $x^{3}+3x^{2}+4x+1$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

There are no divisor of 1 in this polynomial for which would be satisfied $x^{3}+3x^{2}+4x+1=0$. 
How to find roots here?

Comment: If there are no divisors for 1 (I'll take your word for it) then the polynomial is unfactorable and has no rational roots.  Which is too bad, but that doesn't mean it doesn't have real irrational roots.  Indeed it must.

Comment: the answers are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method  which will work when there are no rational roots (so you must work harder), one real irrational root, and two complex conjugate roots.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by hand with a bunch of substitutions.

Let $y=x+1$, then

$$1+4(y-1)+3(y-1)^2+(y-1)^3=0$$

If we expand all the terms we get

$$1+4y-4+3y^2-6y+3+y^3-3y^2+3y-1=0$$

which boils down to

$$y^3+y-1=0$$

Now we can do a change in coordinates with another substitution.

Let $y=u+\frac{\lambda}{u}$. We will find $\lambda$ later. This yields.

$$-1+u+\frac{\lambda}{u}+\left ( u + \frac{\lambda}{u} \right )^3=0$$

We can expand this by multiplying by $u^3$ which gives

$$u^4(3\lambda + 1) + u^2\lambda(3\lambda+1)-u^3+u^6+\lambda^3=0$$

We want the coefficients on the $u^2$ and $u^4$ terms to be $0$. So $\lambda=-\frac{1}{3}$. 
Substituting we now have

$$u^6-u^3-\frac{1}{27}=0$$

If we perform yet another substitution, we can finally get to a quadratic.

Let $z=u^3$.

$$z^2-z+\frac{1}{27}=0$$

Using the quadratic formula we get

$$z=\frac{1}{18}(9+\sqrt{93})$$.

Now we climb back up our ladder of subsitutions

$$u^3=\frac{1}{18}(9+\sqrt{93})$$

$$u=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{18}(9+\sqrt{93})}$$

We substitute for $u$ and get

$$y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{18}(9+\sqrt{93})}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{18}(9+\sqrt{93})}}$$

Now to get $x$ we just subtract 1.

$$x=\left( \frac{1}{18}(9+\sqrt{93})\right )^{1/3} - \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{1}{18}(9+\sqrt{93})\right )^{-1/3}-1$$

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help a bit?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Root[x^3%2B3*x^2%2B4*x%2B1%2C+x]

Comment: I found solution using Matlab, but I was interested in how to calculate it by hand :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The equation has one real solution, but rather ugly I am afraid.

http://www4f.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP41323441hc6heb7fh0000004752i2229938d4f0?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=27&w=286.&h=81.

Comment: Question is, how to get that by hand, without using software :)

Comment: use Cardano formula http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/

Answer (score 0):

Using maxima (I didn't know maxima could do tex(%)).

$$x=-{{{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}}\over{3\,\left({{
 \sqrt{31}}\over{2\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{2}}\right)^{{{1
 }\over{3}}}}}+\left({{\sqrt{31}}\over{2\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}}}+{{1
 }\over{2}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}\,\left(-{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{
 1}\over{2}}\right)-1$$

$$ x=\left({{\sqrt{31}}\over{2\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}
 }}}+{{1}\over{2}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}\,\left({{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{
 2}}-{{1}\over{2}}\right)-{{-{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}
 }\over{3\,\left({{\sqrt{31}}\over{2\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{2
 }}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}-1$$

$$ x=\left({{\sqrt{31}}\over{2\,3^{{{3
 }\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{2}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}-{{1}\over{3\,
 \left({{\sqrt{31}}\over{2\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{2}}\right)
 ^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}-1$$

[image]

Comment: I found solution using Matlab, but I was interested in how to calculate it by hand :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Put $x = y - 1$, this yields:

$$y^3 + y - 1 = 0$$

Then compare with the identity:

$$\begin{split}
(a+b)^3 \equiv a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 3 b a^2 + b^3\Longrightarrow \\
(a+b)^3 - 3 a b (a+b) - (a^3 + b^3) \equiv 0
\end{split}
 $$

So, if we can find two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that:

$$-3 a b = 1$$

and

$$a^3 + b^3 = 1$$

then $y = a + b$ will be a solution.

If we put $A = a^3$ and $B = b^3$, then we require that:

$$A B = -\frac{1}{27}$$

$$A + B = 1$$

Now solving for $A$ and $B$ requires solving a quadratic equation. When extracting $a$ and $b$, you must make sure that $a b = -\frac{1}{3}$, so the choice of the phase factor multiplying the cube root for $A$ fixes the phase factor for $b$.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!